Assign selector value to state and not mutate original selector value when state is changed
I currently have a component that uses a selector with useSelector from react-redux. However, after I set the state with the selector value and then update the state with a onChange event handler, they original selector value will be changed also.
How can I not mutate the original selector object when updating the state?
// Here is how the selectorObject looks

selectorObject = {
  labels: [{ label1: "Hello}]
}


const ComponentA = () => {
  const selectorObject = useSelector(getObjectSelector);
  const [stateObject, setStateObject] = useState(null);
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectorObject) {
         const temp = {...selectorObject}
         // Also tried `const temp = Object.assign({}, ...selectorObject)` but same result 
        setStateObject({...temp })
    {
  }, [selectorObject])

  const handleOnchange = () => {
    const temp = {...selectorObject}
    // Also tried `const temp = Object.assign({}, ...selectorObject)` but same result 
    temp.labels[0].label1 = event.target.value; //Assume event.target.value = "Hello World"
    setStateObject({...temp})

    console.log(stateObject)
    console.log(selectorObject)
  }

  const setData = (data) => {
    const temp = {...data} // Also tried Object.assign({}, data) but still mutates selectorObject
    setStateData(temp)
  }

  return (
    {stateObject.labels.map((data) => {
       <div onClick={() => setData(data)}>
          <MyComponent data={data} handleOnChange={handleOnchange } />
       </div>
    })
  )

}

// MyComponent 

const MyComponent = ({data, handleOnChange}) => {
  return (
    <input defaultValue={data.label1} onChange={handleOnChange} />
  )

}

The two console logs in the handleOnchange function shows that both selectorObject and stateObject have been changed the same and the label proprty is equal to Hello World
What I'm expecting is for selectorObject.label[0].label1 to still equal Hello and stateObject.label[0].label1 to equal the new value Hello World after setting the state in the onChange handler
I thought the spread operator does a deep clone and should not mutate the original
UPDATED CODE. The problem may have to do with the mapping of the stateObject.labels where I then pass stateObject.labels[0] to the child component, which will then have an input that invokes the onChange handler to change the value at stateObject.labels[0].label1

I've copy/pasted your code into a running codesandbox and I'm unable to reproduce the issue as you describe it. The Redux state is un-mutated. That said, the spread syntax is only a shallow copy. Check your code again and ensure you are running your latest changes. Feel free to fork my sandbox and see if you can edit it and reproduce the problem there where we can then inspect it live.

Thanks for input, can you please check again? i added in a few more details

Issue
In order to not mutate the current state all state, and nested state, that is being updated necessarily should be shallow copied into a new reference so React can properly reconcile the state updates, i.e. so React's shallow equality reference checks can tell that a part of the state was updated.
The current code is mutating the previous state reference instead of creating new references.
const handleOnchange = () => {
  const temp = { ...selectorObject }          // <-- only copies selectorObject object

  // temp is a new reference, but `labels` is array reference from current state!
  temp.labels[0].label1 = event.target.value; // <-- mutation!!

  setStateObject({ ...temp })                 // <-- temp.labels is still same reference

  console.log(stateObject)
  console.log(selectorObject)
}

Solution
Use and apply the mutable state update pattern. All state and nested state being updated should be a new object reference. You should also update from the current stateObject state instead of the selected selectorObject value from the store.
const handleOnChange = (event, key) => {
  const temp = {                        // <-- new state reference
    ...stateObject,                     // <-- copy current state
    labels: stateObject.labels.slice(), // <-- new array reference, copied
  };

  temp.labels[0] = {                    // <-- new array element object reference
    ...temp.labels[0],                  // <-- copy current state
    label: event.target.value,          // <-- update property
  };

  setStateObject(temp);
};

A more typical update may look like the following:
const handleOnChange = (event, key) => {
  setStateObject(stateObject => ({               // <-- new state reference
    ...stateObject,                              // <-- shallow copy state
    labels: stateObject.labels.map((label, i) => // <-- new array reference
      i === 0
        ? {                                      // <-- new object reference
          ...label,                              // <-- shallow copy element
          label: event.target.value              // <-- overwrite properties
        }
        : label
    ),
  }));
};


You selectorObject is a reference type (an object), spreading it to create a new object will not create a deep copy. Both stateObject and selectorObject end up pointing to the same object in memory and the situation you described happens.
Just use lodash _.cloneDeep()

I think this problem occurs because of the property of '...' funtion.
When using '...', if the state object has nested objects, the nested objects will still reference the original object.
Try to change the code like this.
const ComponentA = () => {
  const selectorObject = useSelector(getObjectSelector);
  const [stateObject, setStateObject] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectorObject) {
      setStateObject(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectorObject)));
    }
  }, [selectorObject]);

  const handleOnChange = (event, key) => {
    const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stateObject));
    temp[key] = event.target.value; // Assume event.target.value = "Hello World"
    setStateObject(temp);

    console.log(stateObject);
    console.log(selectorObject);
  };
};

export default ComponentA;

